# IIS routing configuration error with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, routes

I am unsure if my title was accurate enough. I am trying to make SEO URLs for my website which is developed in ASP.NET MVC. I configured my route to include:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                                          // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{seo}",                                 // URL with parameters, SEO will up completely optional and used for strings to provide Search Engine Optimization.
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "", seo ="" }     // Parameter defaults
            );
```

On my development machine, a link like:

> http://localhost:1048/Home/Post/96/Firefighting+ATV+Concept+Twin+Water+Cannons+Gull

works fine, but once I published to the server (Windows 2008 R2 IIS), it doesn't work. For example, the link:

> http://www.otakuwire.net/Home/Post/96/Firefighting+ATV+Concept+Twin+Water+Cannons+Gull

gives me a 404.

Is this a routing issue, or some other issue?

Comment: What version of .NET is the server configured to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an IIS issue, not routing. IIS7 is strict in how it deals with the plus symbol `+` in URLs. The easy fix is to use the dash `-` instead like everyone else, or be bold and use the space character (which, personal note, looks horrible in the IE address bar).

On ServerFault they present a configuration-based solution to allow `+` symbols:
https://serverfault.com/questions/76013/iis6-vs-iis7-and-iis7-5-handling-urls-with-plus-sign-in-base-not-querystri

Comment: Yes, you received 404.<something> actually, which was returned by IIS Request Filtering feature. It blocks several patterns of URL including the one you showed.